# Save disabled CSS properties in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: css, google-chrome, developer-tools

When inspecting an element using `Developer Tools` in *Chrome* we have the option to disable style properties by simply unchecking it.

Once I uncheck the box (let's say `border: 1px solid`) the border will disappear and the style property in the editor will appear with a strikethrough but as soon as I click on the 'sources' tab to save the changes out of the editor the unchecked styles return. I have only once noticed when going over to the 'sources' tab to save out the changes, the unchecked styles are commented out allowing me to save the changes without manually removing the code.

Does anyone know how to save out the unchecked (removed) styles?

---

UPDATE:

Okay so I've figured something out. Here's an example:

This is in the DevTools editor;

```
#content .text {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0 0 8px;
}
```

If you uncheck any of these styles, which take effect in your browser immediately, and you then hit the source tab the styles are still there in the stylesheet:

```
#content .text {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0 0 8px;
}
```

BUT, if you make an edit to one of the other properties, let's say, changing the margin to read 7px, whilst unchecking the font-weight this is what you get:

```
#content .text {
    display: block;
    /* font-weight: 700; */
    margin: 0 0 7px;
}
```

Finally the unchecked style is commented out in the sources tab allowing me to save the removed style. I wish this would work without having to make that additional edit but it's going to have to do for now.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem with unchecked styles. I found a slightly easier way of saving the unchecked styles. Just uncheck the style, add another temporary style to your rule and then delete the temporary style. Chrome will document the changes and you will be able to save your unchecked (commented out) style with the "Save-as..." feature in the "Sources" tab.

This is not ideal, but it saves you the hassle of unchecking and modifying a style, doing a "Save-as..." and then going back and changing the modified sytle back to the way it was.

I will definitely bring this up in the Chrome support forum.